# How to make DIVs in a single row

Tags: html, css

I want to display inner divs in a single row without giving width to outer div.
In a given code it is displaying vertically one after the other, if I don't add width.

heres [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nTCny/)

Comment: post only required code in fiddel..if possible post it in your question

Comment: I have no idea what you want. You just put all your code in a JSFiddle and not told us what you want to change in it. Also you should tell us what you have tried to complete this task. This what you mean? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Q9752/)

Comment: Are you trying to display your columns side-by-side? If so, you could try to set the main div to display: table, and the subordinate divs to display: table-cell. But you need to be more clear in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to set the parent element to `display: table` and the child divs to `display: table-cell`. Remove any floats if you choose this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `display: inline-block`to the `col_1`class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what should be on the same line in your example. But if you are talking about the p element with class .btn, you may try to remove 'float: right;' as 'display: inline-block' is enough.